# How to attach click event on body and on table inside body separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML is:

```
<body id="bodyMain">
<table id="myTable" class="table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>UserId</td>
        <td>UserName</td>
        <td>FirstName</td>
        <td>LastName</td>
        <td>PhoneNumber</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Email Id</td>
        <td>UserType</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I have a click event associated with table myTable. It makes that table cell editable. Now I need to attach a event to entire body that checks if clicked region is not table then the textbox that is created using table click will dissappear and the cell value will take its place. The js code is

```
var globalFlag = '';
var prevValue;
var prevHandle = null;

$('#myTable').on('click', 'tbody tr td', function (e) {    
debugger;
console.log($(this).text());
var rowIndex = $(this).parent('tr').index();
var colIndex = $(this).index();
var index = '' + rowIndex + ',' + colIndex;
console.log(index);
if (globalFlag != index && colIndex != 0) {
    //remove initially created textbox
    if (prevHandle != null) {
        prevHandle.find('input[type="text"]').remove();
        prevHandle.text(prevValue);
    }
    prevHandle = $(this);
    prevValue = $(this).text();
    globalFlag = index;
    var valuepresent = $(this).text();
    var txtsize = parseInt($(this).width());
    console.log(txtsize);
    var txt = "<input type='text' value='" + $(this).text() + 
   "'style='width:" + txtsize + "px'>";
    $(this).text('');
    $(this).append(txt);
}
});
$('body').on("click", function () {
debugger;
var th = $(this).attr('id');
var tb = $('#myTable');
if (th != null || th != undefined)
    if (th.indexOf("myTable") >= 0)
        return;
if (prevHandle != null) {
    prevHandle.find('input[type="text"]').remove();
    prevHandle.text(prevValue);
}
});
```

anyhow I try both the events are called one by one. I need that if clicked region is not table then disable editing cell data.
I tried:

```
$('body >:not(#myTable)').on("click", function () {
```

but this did not work. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: `$('body').on("click", function () {`  - but ensure you also `return false` from your cell handler. (or use event.stopPropagation which is the same https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the click event will 'bubble' up from your first (table-cell) handler to the body handler.

You can stop this bubbling by adding

```
return false;
```

at the end of the table-cell click event handler.

This is the same as calling `event.stopPropagation`: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

---

As an aside, you could make your 'close' handler much easier.  Assuming you the only inputs that are shown on the table cells are your inline edits, you can use the `:visible` selector to find the input, eg change the remove to:

```
var inp = $("#myTable input[type='text']:visible");
inp.closest("td").text(inp.val());
inp.remove();
```

that way you don't need to keep track of which input is currently displayed.